# How to install NPM package under alias or different name

Tags: npm, alias, npm-install

How can I `npm install` a package into a different directory?

Answer (score 158, accepted):

Say you want to install [Case](https://www.npmjs.com/package/case) package,
you can have a specific version under an alias:

```
npm i case-1.5.3@npm:case@1.5.3
```

or just give it a different name

```
npm i kool@npm:case
```

If you want to edit package.json directly:

```
"dependencies": {
  "case-1.5.3": "npm:case@^1.5.3",
  "kool": "npm:case@^1.6.1"
}
```

require():

```
let Case = require( 'case-1.5.3' );
let Kool = require( 'kool' );
```

Yarn used to have this functionality for a long time, and npm finally got it since [v6.9.0](https://npm.community/t/release-npm-6-9-0/5911), Mar 2019.

If you want to [update](https://docs.npmjs.com/try-the-latest-stable-version-of-npm) your npm:

```
sudo npm i -g npm@latest
```

Comment: How do you then get specific dependencies to use a package alias? I'm trying to upgrade from material UI 0.x to 4.x in an existing app. I need React 16.3 for 0.x and 16.8 for 4.x

Comment: Is it possible to install a package that has multiple names?

Comment: Thank you so much for including the syntax for the `package.json` - every other answer I came across neglects this.

Comment: This is brilliant! We used that to force a browserified version of dependencies of react-pdf/renderer package, in context where we cannot do it using Webpack aliases

Comment: This is a cool approach, but one drawback I noticed is that sometimes after running `npm install` the package version gets updated in `package-lock.json`. Is there a way to avoid that?

Comment: @szx Specify `1.5.3` not `^1.5.3`. More on semver: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25861938/121240
https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/configuring-npm/package-json#dependencies

Answer (score 5):

with **PNPM**
if want to use two different versions of a package in your project. It is possible with following commands

```
pnpm add <any-alias-name>@npm:package-name

for example 

pnpm add new-lodash@npm:lodash@2
pnpm add old-lodash@npm:lodash@1
```

Now we can use both lodash in our project

```
const newLodash = require('new-lodash');
const oldLodash = require('old-lodash');
```

Note that it worked only for `require` and not for ESM import statement i.e.

```
import oldLodash from 'old-lodash' // will throw error
```

Comment: > Note that it worked only for require and not for ESM import statement…

Any update on this 3 years on? I'm trying to import an alias in an ESM project, and TypeScript says it's ‘not a module.’