# How can I install two versions of Bootstrap with NPM into a single node_modules folder?

Tags: node.js, twitter-bootstrap, npm, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-5

I'm issuing the following npm command to install some files needed by Bootstrap:

```
npm install browser-sync gulp gulp-sass --save-dev
```

After this runs, there are 492 folders that contain over 55 MB files installed into the **node_modules** folder before I've even installed Bootstrap.

I'm trying to install two versions of Bootstrap. I already have version 4 installed, but would also like to install Bootstrap 5 alpha 2, but it seems only one version can live in node_modules at a time. So I have to add a new folder with another node_modules folder full of all these files just to run another version of Bootstrap.

Is there any way I can install two versions of Bootstrap into one **node_modules** folder to avoid all these duplicate files? Thanks.

Comment: Why are you trying to install two versions of Bootstrap? (Asking because it seems likely that "install two versions of Bootstrap" is not the only, or perhaps even best, solution to your problem.)

Comment: @Trott: I need version 4 for a few sites already in development using version 4, but want to also start using version 5 on an experimental site.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into a similar issue, because in my company project I had another websites that needs older version of bootstrap. So, in a research, [based on this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56134857/how-to-install-npm-package-under-alias-or-different-name/56134858#56134858), the  v6.9.0, Mar 2019 of NPM supports aliases. So, all you need to do is to install the duplicated package under an alias, like:

```
npm install legacy-bootstrap@npm:bootstrap@v4.0.0-alpha.6
```

Then, instead of `include/require bootstrap/js/tab.js` you will need to `require legacy-bootstrap/js/tab.js`