# Use forked NPM package as drop in replacement using the same name in devDependencies

Tags: npm, electron

I need to update the Electron version used in my project. Currently the package "electron-prebuilt-compile" is what pulls in Electron. "electron-prebuilt-compile" is currently stuck at Electron version 8. I have found a few forks of "electron-prebuilt-compile" and attempted to use that but unfortunately I get an error saying I need an exact version and not a range.

Is there a way to alias a package in my package.json file? So I can have "electron-prebuilt-compile": "8.2.0" but it instead uses "@felixrieseberg/electron-prebuilt-compile": "9.4.4" (for example).

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**: Actually it looks like a better answer already exists [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56134858/9698583)

```sh
npm i -D electron-prebuilt-compile@npm:@felixrieseberg/electron-prebuilt-compile
```

---

You can point directly to the tarball of the forked package while still using the original name by editing `package.json` like this

```json
"devDependencies": {
  "electron-prebuilt-compile": "https://registry.npmjs.org/@felixrieseberg/electron-prebuilt-compile/-/electron-prebuilt-compile-9.4.4.tgz"
}
```