# How can I install two different versions of the same dependency on the same project?

Tags: angular, webpack, yarnpkg, npx

My question is: how to install all the missing peerDependencies with their different required versions? or How to Install Multiple Versions of the Same Package ?

When i run `npx check-peer-dependencies --yarn --install` OR `npx check-peer-dependencies --findSolutions`

I found this [Solution](https://medium.com/weekly-webtips/how-to-install-multiple-versions-of-the-same-package-in-npm-71c29b12e253) but the problem is that I don't want to change the name of each package because the project is already in production and it would be a lot of work to do after changing the dependency names, all I need is to fix the missing dependency warnings

**the command above gives me that : **

```
npx: installed 40 in 3.1s
  ✅  @angular/animations ^11.0.0 || ^12.0.0-0 is required by @angular/material@11.2.13 (12.2.16 is installed)
  ✅  @angular/animations 12.2.16 is required by @angular/platform-browser@12.2.16 (12.2.16 is installed)
  ✅  @angular/animations >=4 is required by @savantly/ngx-inline-edit@0.3.0 (12.2.16 is installed)
  ❌  @angular/animations ^7.0.0 is required by ng-pick-datetime-moment@1.0.8) (12.2.16 is installed)
  ✅  @angular/cdk 11.2.13 is required by @angular/material@11.2.13 (11.2.13 is installed)
  ❌  @angular/cdk ~2.0.0-beta.12 is required by @savantly/ngx-inline-edit@0.3.0) (11.2.13 is installed)
  ❌  @angular/cdk 2.0.0-beta.12 is required by @angular/material@2.0.0-beta.12) (11.2.13 is installed)
  ❌  @angular/cdk 2.0.0-beta.12 is required by @angular/material@2.0.0-beta.12) (11.2.13 is installed)
  ❌  @angular/cdk ^7.0.0 is required by ng-pick-datetime@7.0.0) (11.2.13 is installed)
  ❌  @angular/common ^7.0.0 is required by @angular-cool/inline-edit-field@1.0.3) (12.2.16 is installed)
  ✅  @angular/common ^11.0.0 || ^12.0.0-0 is required by @angular/cdk@11.2.13 (12.2.16 is installed)
  ✅  @angular/common 12.2.16 is required by @angular/forms@12.2.16 (12.2.16 is installed)
  ✅  @angular/common ^12.0.0 || ^13.0.0-0 is required by @angular/google-maps@12.2.13 (12.2.16 is installed)
  ✅  @angular/common ^11.0.0 || ^12.0.0-0 is required by @angular/material@11.2.13 (12.2.16 is installed)
  ✅  @angular/common 12.2.16 is required by @angular/platform-browser@12.2.16 (12.2.16 is installed)
  ✅  @angular/common 12.2.16 is required by @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@12.2.16 (12.2.16 is installed)
  ✅  @angular/common 12.2.16 is required by @angular/router@12.2.16 (12.2.16 is installed)
  ✅  @angular/common >=5.0.0 is required by @ckeditor/ckeditor5-angular@1.2.3 (12.2.16 is installed)
  ❌  @angular/common >=7.0.0 <9.0.0 is required by @fullcalendar/angular@4.4.2) (12.2.16 is installed)
  ❌  @angular/common >=6.0.0 <8.0.0 is required by @ng-select/ng-select@2.20.5) (12.2.16 is installed)
  ✅  @angular/common >=7.0.0 is required by @ngx-translate/http-loader@4.0.0 (12.2.16 is installed)
  ✅  @angular/common >=4 is required by @savantly/ngx-inline-edit@0.3.0 (12.2.16 is installed)
  ❌  @angular/common ~4.4.4 is required by @angular/cdk@2.0.0-beta.12) (12.2.16 is installed)
  ❌  @angular/common ~4.4.4 is required by @angular/material@2.0.0-beta.12) (12.2.16 is installed)
  ❌  @angular/common <9.0.0 is required by @swimlane/ngx-datatable@16.1.1) (12.2.16 is installed)
  ❌  @angular/common ^7.1.0 is required by inline-edit-directive@1.0.2) (12.2.16 is installed)
  ❌  @angular/common ^2.0.0 is required by @angular/forms@2.0.0) (12.2.16 is installed)
  ❌  @angular/common ~4.4.4 is required by @angular/material@2.0.0-beta.12) (12.2.16 is installed)
  ❌  @angular/common ^2.0.0 is required by @angular/platform-browser@2.0.0) (12.2.16 is installed)
  ❌  @angular/common ^2.0.0 is required by @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@2.0.0) (12.2.16 is installed)
  ❌  @angular/common ^2.0.0 is required by @angular/router@3.0.0) (12.2.16 is installed)
  ❌  @angular/common ^7.0.0 is required by ng-pick-datetime-moment@1.0.8) (12.2.16 is installed)
  ✅  @angular/common >=7.0.0 is required by @angular/cdk@7.3.7 (12.2.16 is installed)
  ❌  @angular/common 7.2.16 is required by @angular/forms@7.2.16) (12.2.16 is installed)
  ✅  @angular/common >=7.0.0 is required by ngx-bootstrap@6.2.0 (12.2.16 is installed)
  ✅  @angular/common >=9.0.0-0 is required by ngx-color@5.1.4 (12.2.16 is installed)
  ✅  @angular/common >= 8.0.0 is required by ngx-infinite-scroll@8.0.2 (12.2.16 is installed)
  ✅  @angular/common 8.x - 13.x is required by ngx-intl-tel-input@3.2.0 (12.2.16 is installed)
  ❌  @angular/common ^7.0.0 || ^8.0.0 is required by ngx-quill@7.3.12) (12.2.16 is installed)
  ✅  @angular/common >=5.0.0 is required by ngx-toastr@8.3.2 (12.2.16 is installed)
  ❌  @angular/common >=5.0.0 <10.0.0 is required by ngx-ui-switch@9.0.2) (12.2.16 is installed)
  ✅  @angular/compiler 12.2.16 is required by @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@12.2.16 (12.2.16 is installed)
  ✅  @angular/compiler >=4 is required by @savantly/ngx-inline-edit@0.3.0 (12.2.16 is installed)
  ❌  @angular/compiler ^2.0.0 is required by @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@2.0.0) (12.2.16 is installed)
  ❌  @angular/core ^7.0.0 is required by @angular-cool/inline-edit-field@1.0.3) (12.2.16 is installed)
  ✅  @angular/core 12.2.16 is required by @angular/animations@12.2.16 (12.2.16 is installed)
  ✅  @angular/core ^11.0.0 || ^12.0.0-0 is required by @angular/cdk@11.2.13 (12.2.16 is installed)
  ✅  @angular/core 12.2.16 is required by @angular/common@12.2.16 (12.2.16 is installed)
  ✅  @angular/core 12.2.16 is required by @angular/forms@12.2.16 (12.2.16 is installed)
  ✅  @angular/core ^12.0.0 || ^13.0.0-0 is required by @angular/google-maps@12.2.13 (12.2.16 is installed)
  ❌  @angular/core 8.0.0-beta.10+1.sha-a28b3e3 is required by @angular/http@8.0.0-beta.10+1.sha-a28b3e3) (12.2.16 is installed)
  ✅  @angular/core ^11.0.0 || ^12.0.0-0 is required by @angular/material@11.2.13 (12.2.16 is installed)
  ✅  @angular/core ^11.0.0 || ^12.0.0-0 is required by @angular/material-moment-adapter@11.2.13 (12.2.16 is installed)
  ✅  @angular/core 12.2.16 is required by @angular/platform-browser@12.2.16 (12.2.16 is installed)
  ✅  @angular/core 12.2.16 is required by @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@12.2.16 (12.2.16 is installed)
  ✅  @angular/core 12.2.16 is required by @angular/router@12.2.16 (12.2.16 is installed)
  ✅  @angular/core >=5.0.0 is required by @ckeditor/ckeditor5-angular@1.2.3 (12.2.16 is installed)
  ❌  @angular/core ^8.0.0-rc.5 is required by @fortawesome/angular-fontawesome@0.5.0) (12.2.16 is installed)
  ❌  @angular/core >=7.0.0 <9.0.0 is required by @fullcalendar/angular@4.4.2) (12.2.16 is installed)
  ❌  @angular/core >=6.0.0 <8.0.0 is required by @ng-select/ng-select@2.20.5) (12.2.16 is installed)
  ✅  @angular/core >=7.0.0 is required by @ngx-translate/core@11.0.1 (12.2.16 is installed)
  ✅  @angular/core >=4 is required by @savantly/ngx-inline-edit@0.3.0 (12.2.16 is installed)
  ❌  @angular/core ~4.4.4 is required by @angular/cdk@2.0.0-beta.12) (12.2.16 is installed)
  ❌  @angular/core 7.2.16 is required by @angular/http@7.2.16) (12.2.16 is installed)
  ❌  @angular/core ~4.4.4 is required by @angular/material@2.0.0-beta.12) (12.2.16 is installed)
  ❌  @angular/core <9.0.0 is required by @swimlane/ngx-datatable@16.1.1) (12.2.16 is installed)
  ❌  @angular/core ^7.1.0 is required by inline-edit-directive@1.0.2) (12.2.16 is installed)
  ❌  @angular/core ^2.0.0 is required by @angular/common@2.0.0) (12.2.16 is installed)
  ❌  @angular/core ^2.0.0 is required by @angular/compiler@2.0.0) (12.2.16 is installed)
  ❌  @angular/core ^2.0.0 is required by @angular/forms@2.0.0) (12.2.16 is installed)
  ❌  @angular/core ^2.0.0 is required by @angular/http@2.0.0) (12.2.16 is installed)
  ❌  @angular/core ~4.4.4 is required by @angular/material@2.0.0-beta.12) (12.2.16 is installed)
  ❌  @angular/core ^2.0.0 is required by @angular/platform-browser@2.0.0) (12.2.16 is installed)
  ❌  @angular/core ^2.0.0 is required by @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@2.0.0) (12.2.16 is installed)
  ❌  @angular/core ^2.0.0 is required by @angular/router@3.0.0) (12.2.16 is installed)
  ❌  @angular/core ^7.0.0 is required by ng-pick-datetime-moment@1.0.8) (12.2.16 is installed)
  ❌  @angular/core 7.2.16 is required by @angular/animations@7.2.16) (12.2.16 is installed)
  ✅  @angular/core >=7.0.0 is required by @angular/cdk@7.3.7 (12.2.16 is installed)
  ❌  @angular/core 7.2.16 is required by @angular/common@7.2.16) (12.2.16 is installed)
  ❌  @angular/core 7.2.16 is required by @angular/forms@7.2.16) (12.2.16 is installed)
  ✅  @angular/core >=7.0.0 is required by ngx-bootstrap@6.2.0 (12.2.16 is installed)
  ✅  @angular/core >=9.0.0-0 is required by ngx-color@5.1.4 (12.2.16 is installed)
  ✅  @angular/core >= 8.0.0 is required by ngx-infinite-scroll@8.0.2 (12.2.16 is installed)
  ✅  @angular/core 8.x - 13.x is required by ngx-intl-tel-input@3.2.0 (12.2.16 is installed)
  ❌  @angular/core ^7.0.0 || ^8.0.0 is required by ngx-quill@7.3.12) (12.2.16 is installed)
  ✅  @angular/core >=5.0.0 is required by ngx-toastr@8.3.2 (12.2.16 is installed)
  ❌  @angular/core >=5.0.0 <10.0.0 is required by ngx-ui-switch@9.0.2) (12.2.16 is installed)
  ✅  @angular/forms ^11.0.0 || ^12.0.0-0 is required by @angular/material@11.2.13 (12.2.16 is installed)
  ✅  @angular/forms >=5.0.0 is required by @ckeditor/ckeditor5-angular@1.2.3 (12.2.16 is installed)
  ❌  @angular/forms >=6.0.0 <8.0.0 is required bysass-loader@7.3.1 (4.46.0 is installed)
  ✅  webpack ^4.0.0 || ^5.0.0 is required by style-loader@1.3.0 (4.46.0 is installed)
  ✅  webpack ^4.0.0 || ^5.0.0 is required by  @ng-select/ng-select@2.20.5) (12.2.16 is installed)
  ✅  @angular/forms >=4 is required by @savantly/ngx-inline-edit@0.3.0 (12.2.16 is installed)
  ❌  @angular/forms ^7.0.0 is required by ng-pick-datetime-moment@1.0.8) (12.2.16 is installed)
  ✅  @angular/forms 8.x - 13.x is required by ngx-intl-tel-input@3.2.0 (12.2.16 is installed)
  ❌  @angular/forms ^7.0.0 || ^8.0.0 is required by ngx-quill@7.3.12) (12.2.16 is installed)
  ❌  @angular/forms >=5.0.0 <10.0.0 is required by ngx-ui-switch@9.0.2) (12.2.16 is installed)
  ✅  @angular/material 11.2.13 is required by @angular/material-moment-adapter@11.2.13 (11.2.13 is installed)
  ❌  @angular/material ~2.0.0-beta.12 is required by @savantly/ngx-inline-edit@0.3.0) (11.2.13 is installed)
  ❌  @angular/material ^8.0.0 || ^9.0.0 is required by ngx-mat-select-search@2.2.0) (11.2.13 is installed)
  ✅  @angular/platform-browser 12.2.16 is required by @angular/forms@12.2.16 (12.2.16 is installed)
  ❌  @angular/platform-browser 8.0.0-beta.10+1.sha-a28b3e3 is required by @angular/http@8.0.0-beta.10+1.sha-a28b3e3) (12.2.16 is installed)
  ✅  @angular/platform-browser 12.2.16 is required by @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@12.2.16 (12.2.16 is installed)sass-loader@7.3.1 (4.46.0 is installed)
  ✅  webpack ^4.0.0 || ^5.0.0 is required by style-loader@1.3.0 (4.46.0 is installed)
  ✅  webpack ^4.0.0 || ^5.0.0 is required by 
  ✅  @angular/platform-browser 12.2.16 is required by @angular/router@12.2.16 (12.2.16 is installed)
  ✅  @angular/platform-browser >=4 is required by @savantly/ngx-inline-edit@0.3.0 (12.2.16 is installed)
  ❌  @angular/platform-browser 7.2.16 is required by @angular/http@7.2.16) (12.2.16 is installed)
  ❌  @angular/platform-browser <9.0.0 is required by @swimlane/ngx-datatable@16.1.1) (12.2.16 is installed)
  ❌  @angular/platform-browser ^2.0.0 is required by @angular/http@2.0.0) (12.2.16 is installed)
  ❌  @angular/platform-browser ^2.0.0 is required by @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@2.0.0) (12.2.16 is installed)
  ❌  @angular/platform-browser ^2.0.0 is required by @angular/router@3.0.0) (12.2.16 is installed)
  ❌  @angular/platform-browser 7.2.16 is required by @angular/forms@7.2.16) (12.2.16 is installed)
  ❌  @angular/platform-browser ^7.0.0 || ^8.0.0 is required by ngx-quill@7.3.12) (12.2.16 is installed)
  ✅  @angular/platform-browser >=5.0.0 is required by ngx-toastr@8.3.2 (12.2.16 is installed)
  ❌  @fortawesome/angular-fontawesome ^0.2.1 is required by @angular-cool/inline-edit-field@1.0.3) (0.5.0 is installed)
  ❌  @fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core ^1.2.9 is required by @angular-cool/inline-edit-field@1.0.3) (6.1.1 is installed)
  ❌  @fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core ^1.2.21 is required by @fortawesome/angular-fontawesome@0.5.0) (6.1.1 is installed)
  ❌  ajv ^8.8.2 is required by ajv-keywords@5.1.0) (6.12.6 is installed)
  ❌  ajv ^8.8.2 is required by ajv-keywords@5.1.0) (6.12.6 is installed)
  ✅  ajv ^6.9.1 is required by ajv-keywords@3.5.2 (6.12.6 is installed)
  ✅  ajv >=5.0.0 is required by ajv-errors@1.0.1 (6.12.6 is installed)
  ✅  rxjs ^6.3.3 is required by @angular-cool/inline-edit-field@1.0.3 (6.6.7 is installed)
  ✅  rxjs ^6.5.3 || ^7.0.0 is required by @angular/common@12.2.16 (6.6.7 is installed)
  ✅  rxjs ^6.5.3 || ^7.0.0 is required by @angular/core@12.2.16 (6.6.7 is installed)
  ✅  rxjs ^6.5.3 || ^7.0.0 is required by @angular/forms@12.2.16 (6.6.7 is installed)
  ✅  rxjs ^6.5.3 || ^7.0.0 is required by @angular/google-maps@12.2.13 (6.6.7 is installed)
  ✅  rxjs ^6.0.0 is required by @angular/http@8.0.0-beta.10+1.sha-a28b3e3 (6.6.7 is installed)
  ✅  rxjs ^6.5.3 || ^7.0.0 is required by @angular/router@12.2.16 (6.6.7 is installed)
  ✅  rxjs >=6.3.0 is required by @ngx-translate/core@11.0.1 (6.6.7 is installed)
  ✅  rxjs >=6.3.0 is required by @ngx-translate/http-loader@4.0.0 (6.6.7 is installed)
  ❌  rxjs ^5.5.2 is required by @savantly/ngx-inline-edit@0.3.0) (6.6.7 is installed)
  ✅  rxjs ^6.0.0 is required by @angular/http@7.2.16 (6.6.7 is installed)
  ✅  rxjs ^6.5.2 is required by @swimlane/ngx-datatable@16.1.1 (6.6.7 is installed)
  ❌  rxjs 5.0.0-beta.12 is required by @angular/core@2.0.0) (6.6.7 is installed)
  ❌  rxjs 5.0.0-beta.12 is required by @angular/http@2.0.0) (6.6.7 is installed)
  ❌  rxjs 5.0.0-beta.12 is required by @angular/router@3.0.0) (6.6.7 is installed)
  ✅  rxjs ^6.0.0 is required by @angular/common@7.2.16 (6.6.7 is installed)
  ✅  rxjs ^6.0.0 is required by @angular/core@7.2.16 (6.6.7 is installed)
  ✅  rxjs ^6.0.0 is required by @angular/forms@7.2.16 (6.6.7 is installed)
  ✅  rxjs ^6.4.0 || ^6.5.0 is required by ngx-quill@7.3.12 (6.6.7 is installed)
  ✅  rxjs >=5.5.0 is required by ngx-toastr@8.3.2 (6.6.7 is installed)
  ❌  webpack ^5.0.0 is required by css-minimizer-webpack-plugin@3.4.1) (4.46.0 is installed)
  ❌  webpack ^5.1.0 is required by html-minimizer-webpack-plugin@3.5.0) (4.46.0 is installed)
  ❌  webpack ^5.1.0 is required by terser-webpack-plugin@5.3.3) (4.46.0 is installed)
  ✅  webpack ^4.0.0 || ^5.0.0 is required by webpack-dev-server@3.11.3 (4.46.0 is installed)
  ✅  webpack ^4.0.0 || ^5.0.0 is required by webpack-dev-middleware@3.7.3 (4.46.0 is installed)
  ✅  webpack >=2 is required by babel-loader@8.2.5 (4.46.0 is installed)
  ✅  webpack ^4.0.0 || ^5.0.0 is required by compression-webpack-plugin@4.0.1 (4.46.0 is installed)
  ✅  webpack ^4.0.0 || ^5.0.0 is required by css-loader@3.6.0 (4.46.0 is installed)
  ✅  webpack ^4.0.0 is required by file-loader@4.3.0 (4.46.0 is installed)
  ✅  webpack ^4.4.0 is required by mini-css-extract-plugin@0.8.2 (4.46.0 is installed)
  ✅  webpack ^4.0.0 is required by optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin@5.0.8 (4.46.0 is installed)
  ✅  webpack ^3.0.0 || ^4.0.0 is required by sass-loader@7.3.1 (4.46.0 is installed)
  ✅  webpack ^4.0.0 || ^5.0.0 is required by style-loader@1.3.0 (4.46.0 is installed)
  ✅  webpack ^4.0.0 || ^5.0.0 is required by terser-webpack-plugin@2.3.8 (4.46.0 is installed)
  ✅  webpack ^4.0.0 is required by terser-webpack-plugin@1.4.5 (4.46.0 is installed)
  ✅  webpack >=4.4.0 is required by webpack-assets-manifest@3.1.1 (4.46.0 is installed)
  ✅  webpack 4.x.x is required by webpack-cli@3.3.12 (4.46.0 is installed)
  ✅  webpack ^4.36.0 || ^5.0.0 is required by sass-loader@8.0.2 (4.46.0 is installed)
  ✅  zone.js ~0.11.4 is required by @angular/core@12.2.16 (0.11.6 is installed)
  ❌  zone.js ^0.8.14 is required by @savantly/ngx-inline-edit@0.3.0) (0.11.6 is installed)
  ❌  zone.js ^0.6.21 is required by @angular/core@2.0.0) (0.11.6 is installed)
  ❌  zone.js ~0.8.26 is required by @angular/core@7.2.16) (0.11.6 is installed)

Searching for solutions for 75 missing dependencies...

  ❌  Unable to find a version of @angular/animations that satisfies the following peerDependencies: ^11.0.0 || ^12.0.0-0 and 12.2.16 and >=4 and ^7.0.0
  ❌  Unable to find a version of @angular/cdk that satisfies the following peerDependencies: 11.2.13 and ~2.0.0-beta.12 and 2.0.0-beta.12 and ^7.0.0
  ❌  Unable to find a version of @angular/common that satisfies the following peerDependencies: ^7.0.0 and ^11.0.0 || ^12.0.0-0 and 12.2.16 and ^12.0.0 || ^13.0.0-0 and >=5.0.0 and >=7.0.0 <9.0.0 and >=6.0.0 <8.0.0 and >=7.0.0 and >=4 and ~4.4.4 and <9.0.0 and ^7.1.0 and ^2.0.0 and 7.2.16 and >=9.0.0-0 and >= 8.0.0 and 8.x - 13.x and ^7.0.0 || ^8.0.0 and >=5.0.0 <10.0.0
  ❌  Unable to find a version of @angular/compiler that satisfies the following peerDependencies: 12.2.16 and >=4 and ^2.0.0
  ❌  Unable to find a version of @angular/core that satisfies the following peerDependencies: ^7.0.0 and 12.2.16 and ^11.0.0 || ^12.0.0-0 and ^12.0.0 || ^13.0.0-0 and 8.0.0-beta.10+1.sha-a28b3e3 and >=5.0.0 and ^8.0.0-rc.5 and >=7.0.0 <9.0.0 and >=6.0.0 <8.0.0 and >=7.0.0 and >=4 and ~4.4.4 and 7.2.16 and <9.0.0 and ^7.1.0 and ^2.0.0 and >=9.0.0-0 and >= 8.0.0 and 8.x - 13.x and ^7.0.0 || ^8.0.0 and >=5.0.0 <10.0.0
  ❌  Unable to find a version of @angular/forms that satisfies the following peerDependencies: ^11.0.0 || ^12.0.0-0 and >=5.0.0 and >=6.0.0 <8.0.0 and >=4 and ^7.0.0 and 8.x - 13.x and ^7.0.0 || ^8.0.0 and >=5.0.0 <10.0.0
  ❌  Unable to find a version of @angular/material that satisfies the following peerDependencies: 11.2.13 and ~2.0.0-beta.12 and ^8.0.0 || ^9.0.0
  ❌  Unable to find a version of @angular/platform-browser that satisfies the following peerDependencies: 12.2.16 and 8.0.0-beta.10+1.sha-a28b3e3 and >=4 and 7.2.16 and <9.0.0 and ^2.0.0 and ^7.0.0 || ^8.0.0 and >=5.0.0
  ❌  Unable to find a version of ajv that satisfies the following peerDependencies: ^8.8.2 and ^8.0.0 and ^6.9.1 and >=5.0.0
  ❌  Unable to find a version of rxjs that satisfies the following peerDependencies: ^6.3.3 and ^6.5.3 || ^7.0.0 and ^6.0.0 and >=6.3.0 and ^5.5.2 and ^6.5.2 and 5.0.0-beta.12 and ^6.4.0 || ^6.5.0 and >=5.5.0
  ❌  Unable to find a version of webpack that satisfies the following peerDependencies: ^5.0.0 and ^5.1.0 and ^4.0.0 || ^5.0.0 and >=2 and ^4.0.0 and ^4.4.0 and ^3.0.0 || ^4.0.0 and >=4.4.0 and 4.x.x and ^4.36.0 || ^5.0.0
  ❌  Unable to find a version of zone.js that satisfies the following peerDependencies: ~0.11.4 and ^0.8.14 and ^0.6.21 and ~0.8.26
```

Comment: You should not install two version of the same dependency. You should adapt your code so that it support the latest version. This will allow you to take advantage of the new features and security fix of that dependency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use aliases if you really need to do this. Look up npm aliasing.

@angular/common: '13.0.0',
@myangular-custom: '4.0.0

Please don't take this example literally but this is the gist of it.?
This should better answer your question...

[How to install NPM package under alias or different name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56134857/how-to-install-npm-package-under-alias-or-different-name)