# "npm install" results in errors when trying to buildin sync-cloud-server

Tags: node.js, npm

I am trying build this cloud-sync-server:

https://github.com/2-IMMERSE/cloud-sync

When running `npm install` I get these errors:

```
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: synckit-cloud@2.0.0
npm ERR! Found: grunt@1.6.1
npm ERR! node_modules/grunt
npm ERR!   dev grunt@"^1.0.1" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer grunt@"~0.4.5" from grunt-typescript@0.8.0
npm ERR! node_modules/grunt-typescript
npm ERR!   dev grunt-typescript@"^0.8.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

I tried everything I know with my tiny knowledge:

```
npm --force
npm --legacy-peer-deps
npm audit fix
npm audit fix --force
```

I even tried different node-version: v14 tells me to upgrade to v16 or above, but even 16-20 give the same error...

Any idea?

Thanks a lot!

I tried everything I know with my tiny knowledge:

```
npm --force
npm --legacy-peer-deps
npm audit fix
npm audit fix --force
```

I even tried different node-version: v14 tells me to upgrade to v16 or above, but even 16-20 give the same error...

Any idea?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need to use an alias for dependency of your main project in order to don't collide with your dependency of dependency (grunt 1.6.1 as your main dep is colliding with a dependency of your grunt-typescript@0.8.0)

So if you update your package.json to

```
"devDependencies": {
    "grunt-1.0.1": "npm:grunt@^1.0.1",
...
```

it should work

ps: FYI [How to install NPM package under alias or different name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56134857/how-to-install-npm-package-under-alias-or-different-name)